# Formik: onBlur handler on useField hook

Tags: reactjs, placeholder, formik

### onBlur handler and real time validation on useField hook

Hello!

I started learning and practicing Formik, but ran into one problem. My project uses custom placeholders that move up with the focus field.

#### What do I need for this❓

- Functional component with isFocused state
- Change it with `onFocus` and `onBlur`
- Depending on the state, change the position of the placeholder

#### Started to do

To do this, I made a component `CustomField` with the `useField()`hook. Works, cool

But later he noticed that real time validation and error messages stopped working ‍♂️. Because I redefined `onBlur` handler. After searching, studying the problem did not find a solution using `onBlur` handler without interfering with Formik.

#### Prepared Sandbox    [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rain-wgdy9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**Please tell me what and where I missed, how can this be implemented? Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution.

My work around for this is to make continue to make use of the onBlur function provided by formik, but also to use your function. This is done by passing the field onBlur function to your handleBlur function and calling it on execution. You can see the changes in this sandbox.

So the two areas of change is this line

```
onBlur={e => handleBlur(field.onBlur, e)}
```

and

```
  function handleBlur(formikBlur, event) {
    if (!(field.value.length > 0)) {
      onFocus(false);
    }
    formikBlur(event);
  }
```

To make use of the formik onBlur function :D 
Good luck

Here is the code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-gagarin-g07zk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, they are the same, but this option is more beautiful and well readable!

Thanks [Kinbaum](https://github.com/Kinbaum)!

> In your `handleBlur` function, you can call `field.onBlur` and pass the synthetic event to it.
>   Something like this:

```
function handleBlur(e) {
    // Call the Formik onBlur event before your custom stuff
    field.onBlur(e);

    if (!field.value.length > 0) {
        onFocus(false);
    }
}
```

[GitHub Issue Answer](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/2064#issuecomment-558421172)

Working code  [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rain-wgdy9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: how to show error on input field onBlur event, i m using for username check, how set error on input field.

Comment: Note: `onFocus(false)` is specific to the example on the github issue answer, and is not necessary to answer this question. You only need to run field.onBlur(e).